# Yii framework How to integrate login form in header that should be visible on every page ,

Tags: yii

I have three module 1 ) client 2 )  producer and search , I want to show login form in header

Login form is for producer , means producer can login

themes\mytheme\views\layouts

```
<div id=weppr>
  <div class=fr header-right>
      <?php $form=$this->beginWidget(CActiveForm, array(
        id=>login-form,
        enableClientValidation=>true,
        clientOptions=>array(
        validateOnSubmit=>true,
        ),
)); 
    echo $form->textField($model,username,array(placeholder=>Enter Email,class=>login-input)); 
    echo $form->passwordField($model,password,array(placeholder=>Enter Password,class=>login-input)); 
    echo CHtml::submitButton(Login,array(class=>login-button));
    $this->endWidget(); 
    <div>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
```

It gives error ,

Is possible to put in main.php , Is it acceptable coding , If not please how to do , and how to integrate login page that should be visible on every page with different module

Comment: Look at portlet widget, and put it to layout.

Comment: in main layout just add a link for login which will be shown only if the user is guest and ehile clicking on that link show a lightbox containing the login form

Comment: But it is out of scope , cant be change requirement , sooo

Comment: can you give the Error?

Comment: Guess it gives error because it is submitted into wrong action. As @ineersa suggested try portlet, or widget

Comment: Undefined variable: model , But i defined model as $model=new LoginFormProducer;  and render as  $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model,'quickSearchModel'=>$quickSearchModel));

Comment: It's layout - not view. You cant do like this. To achieve what you want - you need to make widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try something like this:

LoginWidget.php

```
<?php  class LoginWidget extends CWidget {
public function run() {
    $model = new LoginFormModel;
    $form= $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'login-form',
        'action'=>array('site/login'),
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        )
    ));
    echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('placeholder'=>'Enter Email',class=>'login-input'));
    echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('placeholder'=>'Enter Password',class=>'login-input'));
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Login',array(class=>'login-button'));
    $this->endWidget();
} } ?>
```

In your Layout File:

```
<?php $this->widget('LoginWidget'); ?>
```

That should do it!

Comment: I think, you forgot to set the `action` property on the `CActiveForm`. Something like `'action' => array('site/login')`. Otherwhise the form would submit to the current action and the login data would never get processed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've modified the answer to reflect this